# Is there any need to use "static" keyword for final variables in Java?

Tags: java, variables, static, constants, final

I am confused with `final` and `static` keywords in Java and I need to be clarified about the following issues:

**1.** For variables, is there any need to use `static`? For example:

```
public final int ERROR_CODE = 200;
```

I think there is no need to use `static` as shown below. Am I wrong?

```
public static final int ERROR_CODE = 200;
```

**2.** As far as I know, static is meaningful for methods, classes to use them without creating their instances. **BUT**, also using a `static` variable in this static methods is also meaningful to change their values at the same time:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static int myVariable = 0; 
}

//Now in some other code creating two instances of MyClass
//and altering the variable will affect all instances

MyClass instance1 = new MyClass();
MyClass instance2 = new MyClass();

MyClass.myVariable = 5;  //This change is reflected in both instances
```

**3.** Can I change the order of final and static keywords e.g.

```
public static final int ERROR_CODE = 200;
```

or

```
public final static int ERROR_CODE = 200;
```

Comment: A static final field is a constant belonging to the class. A non-static final field is immutable on the instance it belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` and `final` are different concepts. A `static` member belongs to a class instead of an instance whereas you can not re-assign a `final` variable.

> MyClass.myVariable = 5;  //This change is reflected in both instances

➡️ It would not have been possible had `myVariable` been declared `final`.

> Can I change the order of final and static keywords e.g.
>
> public static final int ERROR_CODE = 200;  or
>
> public final static int ERROR_CODE = 200;

➡️ Yes. It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Except from my 3rd question, the others is  not understood completely. In **#1** meant that, if I define a final variable in a public class, is there any need to use static keyword?

Comment: *if I define a final variable in a public class, is there any need to use static keyword?* - No. If you declare it as `static`, you can access it without creating an instance. But in any case, you won't be able to re-assign it i.e. it's value can not be changed. On the other hand, if it is `static` but not `final`, you can re-assign it. They have no relation with each other.

Comment: I meant in the same class.

Comment: For my **#2** nd question, I meant that if we talk about the same class or method, static is not meaningful as we do not need to use the same instance. Is that true?

Comment: A `static` method can access only `static` variables directly (i.e. without creating an instance). In other words, using the keyword, `static` is mandatory for a variable if you want it to be accessible directly in a `static` method.

Comment: Note that if you leave off `final`, you're forcing every object of that type to take extra memory for that value.

Comment: Final questions :) **#1** If we use final variables as constant, should we define them as `static final` or just `final` for constant variable definition? Is there any difference for better memory usage?

Comment: **#2** Can we describe `final` as **"assign once"** and `static` as **"just a single instance**" ?

Comment: @Jasmine - You have termed `final` correctly but `static` should be termed as `same for all instances`  because it belongs to the class and therefore its value is same for all the instances.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

#1 Initializing a non static final variable with a literal:

```
class MyClass {
   public final int ERROR_CODE = 200;
}
```

A bad practice since:

1. Each instance of the class will have a copy of this variable with the same value, since it's intended to be used as a global constant this is a waste of memory.
2. Static access to the constant is not possible, so `MyClass.ERROR_CODE` will not compile, if you just need this value you always need an instance e.g. `new MyClass().ERROR_CODE`

#2 Static variable

A static variable is useful in several cases, e.g. singleton patterns or class-related caches, or simply when you want to share some common data between all instances of the same class

#3 Yes

Comment: Except from my 3rd question, the others is  not understood completely. In **#1** meant that, if I define a final variable in a public class, is there any need to use static keyword?

Comment: @Jasmine If you don't set it static then the variable is replicated to each instance, as I said, waste of memory. Note also that in this case you will not be able to use this constant without an instance of this class

Comment: Final questions :) **#1** If we use final variables as constant, should we define them as `static final` or just `final` for constant variable definition? Is there any difference for better memory usage?

Comment: **#2** Can we describe `final` as **"assign once"** and `static` as **"just a single instance**" ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your class hasn’t gotten to this yet, but a class is an object, managed by a classloader. The classloader loads the class and makes sure there is only one class object. The class object is where static variables and methods live.

For #1, static means there is one variable that belongs to the class. The declaration without static means it is an instance variable, and every instance you create of that class has its own variable. For constants, make your variable static final so there is just one.

Final means the value doesn’t change. If the variable is a primitive then you can’t reassign the value. If the variable is a reference type then you can’t change what the variable points to. If the object pointed to is mutable itself, final doesn’t change that.

For 2, static variables belong to the class, one of your static methods can change what’s in the variable and other methods can see the change. Global mutable state is confusing to reason about, also you are leaving OO good practice behind and entering a domain of dirty hacks, so it’s a good idea to be very cautious about using this feature.

#3: come on you can try this out for yourself in about 10 seconds. Either way works. The [google style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.8-specific-constructs) advises “static final”.

Comment: Final questions :) **#1** If we use final variables as constant, should we define them as `static final` or just `final` for constant variable definition? Is there any difference for better memory usage?

Comment: **#2** Can we describe `final` as **"assign once"** and `static` as **"just a single instance**" ?

Comment: @Jasmine: you can sat static is a single instance per classloader. Final is assign once on initialization.

Answer (score 0):

1: `static` is not *needed* as long as the constant is only accessed from within an instance (or using an instance). But to access it without having  an instance, it must be `static`. More important IMHO, it should be a class variable since there makes no sense to have an instance variable that is constant (independent of the instance) - see also next point.

2: that what you described is the functionality - kind of related, the data design, the data model, `static` indicates a class member (field, method) in contrast to an instance member - important part of OO design

3: the order is not important... but, the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3-220) *suggests*:

> MethodModifier:
> (one of)
> [Annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-9.html#jls-Annotation) **public protected private
> abstract static final synchronized native strictfp**
> ...
> If two or more (distinct) method modifiers appear in a method declaration, it is customary, though not required, that they appear in the order consistent with that shown above in the production for MethodModifier.

Comment: Final questions :) **#1** If we use final variables as constant, should we define them as `static final` or just `final` for constant variable definition? Is there any difference for better memory usage?

Comment: **#2** Can we describe `final` as **"assign once"** and `static` as **"just a single instance**" ?